# Как сделать ограничения на количество запусков программы в день?

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter

Задача состоит в следующем: **необходимо, чтобы программу можно было запускать не более 6 раз в день**,т.е. после 6 запусков программу можно было запустить только на следующий день. В моей программе есть два текстовых файла 1 - счетчик и 2 - файл с датой. Сделана проверка на счетчик и файл с датой,в программе проверяется текущая дата и дата из файла, если дата из файла и дата текущая не совпадают, то счетчик обновляется, однако с 54 строки проверка не срабатывает как надо. В коде отметил  область в которой проблемы.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('300x300')


def develop_label(mark_index):
    marks = ['1', '2', '3']
    lbl1['text'] = marks[mark_index]  
    if mark_index == len(marks) - 1:  
        mark_index = -1
    root.after(5000, develop_label, mark_index + 1)  


lbl1 = Label(text='1', font='TimesNewRoman 12')
lbl1.place(x=120, y=10)


######Исправить
file = open('count.txt', 'r+')#файл с кол-вом запусков
N=file.read(1)

file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+') ##файл с датой




data_in_file = ''

date_now = datetime.date.today()
date_now1 = str(date_now)
file.close()


file = open('count.txt', 'r+')
file.seek(0)
N = int(N)
N += 1
file.write(str(N))


if N == 0:
    file2.seek(0)
    file2.write(str(date_now))
    file2.close()
    file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+')
    data_in_file = file2.read()
    file2.close()
    print('aboba')

if int(N) >= 6:
    print('rabotaet')
    if date_now1 != data_in_file:

        file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+')
        file2.seek(0)
        file2.write(str(date_now))
        N = 0
        file.write(str(N))

    else:
        print('data rabotat')
        exit()

    
######

k = 0
def correct():
    global k
    path = "C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\fuf"
    file_name = 'test.py'
    file_path = os.path.join(path,file_name)    
    a = field.get()
    if a == "йцу":
        print('asdasd')
        lbl2 = Label(root, text = 'Correct',borderwidth = 5)
        lbl2.place(x=120, y=50)
        
    else:
        lbl2 = Label(root, text = 'Incorrect')
        lbl2.place(x=120, y=50)
        k += 1
        print(k)
        if k == 3:
            print(k,"yeees")
            #os.remove(file_path)
            root.destroy()
        
        
field = Entry()
field.place(x=100, y=100)
file.close()
file2.close()
butt = Button(root, text ="go", command = lambda:correct())
butt.place(x=100, y=200)
root.after(0, develop_label, 0)  # (интервал в мс, функция, аргумент функции)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикладываю код, того, что вы хотите. Начиная со строчки `root = Tk()` вставляйте код своей основной программы. Функцции (`def`) можете вставить и перед кодом или внутри него.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime


date_file = open('date.txt', 'r+')
last_launch_date = date_file.read()
today_date = str(datetime.date.today())

if last_launch_date == today_date:  # если в файле сегодняшняя дата
    counter_file = open('count.txt', 'r+')
    launches_today = int(counter_file.read()) + 1
    counter_file.close()
    counter_file = open('count.txt', 'w')  # перезаписываем файл
    counter_file.write(str(launches_today))  # переписываем кол-во запусков
    counter_file.close()
    if launches_today > 6:
        exit()
else:  # даты не соответствуют
    date_file.close()
    date_file = open('date.txt', 'w')  # перезаписываем файл
    date_file.write(today_date)  # переписываем дату запуска
    counter_file = open('count.txt', 'w')
    counter_file.write('1')
    counter_file.close()

date_file.close()

# Ниже основной код программы:
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Тоже самое, но с конструкциями `with open() as` - код короче, понятнее и закрывает файл сразу после завершения работы с ним:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

with open('date.txt', 'r+') as date_file:
    last_launch_date = date_file.read()
today_date = str(datetime.date.today())

if last_launch_date == today_date:  # если в файле сегодняшняя дата
    with open('count.txt', 'r+') as counter_file:
        launches_today = int(counter_file.read()) + 1
    with open('count.txt', 'w') as counter_file: # перезаписываем файл
        counter_file.write(str(launches_today))  # переписываем кол-во запусков
    if launches_today > 6:
        exit()
else:  # даты не соответствуют
    with open('date.txt', 'w') as date_file:  # перезаписываем файл
        date_file.write(today_date)  # переписываем дату запуска
    with open('count.txt', 'w') as counter_file:
        counter_file.write('1')

# Ниже основной код программы:
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: спасибо, но есть вопрос: при совершении 6 запусков программа не запускается(то что нужно было), но при попытке смене даты, например, на 26, то можно совершить один запуск после чего выдаёт ошибку: launches_today = int(counter_file.read()) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @asd123 у вас при первом запуске должен быть файл count.txt и в нём нужно написать 0

Comment: т.е. я не могу например в date.txt поменять дату на следующую и число в файле count обнулится и программа запуститься заного?

Comment: @asd123 можете. Один раз перед самым первым запуском запишите 0 в файл count.txt . Далее можете менять даты, и счетчик будет обновляться

Comment: просто я сейчас поставил в файле count.txt ноль и запустил программу, сделал 6 запусков, после чего поставил дату новую, запустил опять и на второй попытке запуска мне выдало ошибку ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Видимо, я что-то не так делаю><

Comment: @asd123 я проделывал такой сценарий и сейчас снова проделал, у меня всё корректо работает. По коду вашей ошибки видно, что у вас в этот момент файл count.txt пустой. Вы программу останавливаете? т.е. нужно на кнопку stop нажимать в вашей IDE, где у вас код написан

Comment: Я использую стандартную IDLE питона,  для запуска программы мне приходится полностью заного запускать программу, видимо проблема в этом.

Comment: @asd123 вижу, строчка потерялась, скопируйте код ещё раз или добавьте вручную в блоке else строку ```counter_file.close()```

Comment: Теперь все идеально работает, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ и помощь, премного  благодарен.